# Listen for scroll up / down?

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I'm building an app (ES6) and I'm curious what is the 'correct' way to catch scroll up / down events?

I tried (npm) installing react-scroll-listener but I couldn't get it to work with my ES6 class.

Basically I want: if scroll up, do this; if scroll down, do something else.

```
import React from 'react';
import config from '../config';
import StaticImageList from '../Common/StaticImageList';
import ScrollListener from 'react-scroll-listener';

class Album extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

    }
    myScrollStartHandler(){
        console.log('Scroll start');

    }
    myScrollEndHandler(){
        console.log('Scroll end 300ms(default)');
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      scrollListener.addScrollHandler('body', myScrollStartHandler, myScrollEndHandler );
    }
    render(){
      return <StaticImageList />;
    }
};

export default Album;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is general advice for hooking into any listeners:

Attach stuff in `componentDidMount`, unattach in `componentWillUnmount`

```
class Whatever extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, { passive: true })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  }

  handleScroll(event) {
    // do something like call `this.setState`
    // access window.scrollY etc
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect. What is the best cross-browser way to distinguish scroll up from scroll down?

Comment: just record the scrollY value and see if the next one is less than or greater than

Comment: How can you catch a wheel event on an element with overflow hidden? (i.e. nothing to scroll, but still want to use wheel event as trigger).

Comment: Not firing for me

Comment: Almost perfect answer. Would be nice if you add a `this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)` right before addEventListener call. Without it people won't be able to call this.setState as `this` will refer to window or other element instead of the current component class. @bierhier this may be why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 15):

Actually there are many ways to do it, but using React hooks was the easier one for me, all you need to do is:

- define a state for scroll position
- a function to update your scroll position state
- start a scroll listen when component mounts
- stop the listen when component unmount

Something like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

...
// inside component:

const [scrollPosition, setSrollPosition] = useState(0);
const handleScroll = () => {
    const position = window.pageYOffset;
    setSrollPosition(position);
};

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true });

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
}, []);
```

Now you have scrollPosition in pixels to work on

In this particular case useEffect will be equivalent to componentDidMount because it will be fired once the component mounts, but also after all updates, **but** `addEventListener` is smart enough to not start duplicated listeners.

The return inside of useEffect is equivalent to componentWillUnmount, it'll "called" when the component unmounts.

Comment: addEventListener would register multiple handlers, since they're different functions for each render. They won't be registered multiple times anyway, but that's because you've provided an empty dependency array to useEffect, which essentially will make the effect run once on mount, and cleanup once on unmount.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, is there a way to check the handlers on console?

Comment: This does not work in Chrome. window.pageYOffset will always return 0.