# How to window.addEventListener in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to figure out how to implement window.addEventListener in React. I'm developing a website with Gatsby and in "development" environment it works but whenever I start in production it gets an error. This is my code:

```
const checkHeader = () => { 
    // Detect scroll position
    let viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    if (viewportWidth > 1100) {
        let scrollPosition = Math.round(window.scrollY);

        if (scrollPosition > 100){
            document.querySelector('#nav').classList.add(`${headerStyles.sticky}`);
        }
        else {
            document.querySelector('#nav').classList.remove(`${headerStyles.sticky}`);
        }

    } else {

    }
};

// Run the checkHeader function every time you scroll
window.addEventListener('scroll', checkHeader);
```

I want to apply a class when Scroll. I've checked that I can't use "window." in React. How is the way to implement this code in React?

Comment: wats the error u get?

Comment: Also if u r using react.. there are chances your applied class suddenly disappears when DOM re-renders. You should modify the state in the `eventlistener` and set the class based on the state varaible in the rendeer.

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980371/react-listen-for-scroll-up-down

Comment: https://usehooks.com/useOnScreen/  - Create an Intersection observer React Hook :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> During *development*, react components are only run in the browser where `window` is defined. When *building*, Gatsby renders these components on the server where `window` is not defined.
>
> Generally with React, the solution is to only access `window` in componentDidMount or to check that window exists before accessing it.

```
const checkHeader = () => { 
    // Detect scroll position
    let viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    if (viewportWidth > 1100) {
        let scrollPosition = Math.round(window.scrollY);

        if (scrollPosition > 100){
            document.querySelector('#nav').classList.add(`${headerStyles.sticky}`);
        }
        else {
            document.querySelector('#nav').classList.remove(`${headerStyles.sticky}`);
        }

    } else {

    }
};

// Check that window exists before accessing it
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // Run the checkHeader function every time you scroll
    window.addEventListener('scroll', checkHeader);
}
```

Comment: just missing the if statement, thank you! it works! really appreciate!

Comment: Is it a right way to use querySelector in reactjs? @ksav

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add window events with Gatsby since it performs server side rendering. To do that you need to add you listeners in `gatsby-browser.js` inside [`onClientEntry`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onClientEntry) method which is called when client is loaded

```
// gatsby-browser.js
// ES6


const checkHeader = () => { 
    // Detect scroll position
    let viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    if (viewportWidth > 1100) {
        let scrollPosition = Math.round(window.scrollY);

        if (scrollPosition > 100){
            document.querySelector('#nav').classList.add(`${headerStyles.sticky}`);
        }
        else {
            document.querySelector('#nav').classList.remove(`${headerStyles.sticky}`);
        }

    } else {

    }
};


export const onClientEntry = () => {
   // Run the checkHeader function every time you scroll
   window.addEventListener('scroll', checkHeader);
}
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, I am starting with Gatsby and I will check the gastby-browser method! any resource to learn about? thank you for your time!

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onClientEntry. This is the right way to go instead of adding an if condition

Comment: Ok, I must change my site structure theme. Never work with gatby-browser before! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling the function on `did mount` of the root component might solve your issue. for example:

```
// your entry component
const App = () => {

  React.useEffect(() => { // Will be called after mounting the componnent.
    onClientEntry();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Home />
  );
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks Vishnu for your response. I will check this method too, thank you for your time ;)